# How to change password in java,if it is encrypted using MD5 ?

Tags: java, md5

I am working on changing password, but the old password is decrypted using MD5.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is poor question. Please, provide your code.

Comment: well, where exactly is the problem? just provide the old password and hash it again. if the md5-hash values are equal you can change it

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to request the user to enter his old password and his new password.

Once that is done, do a md5 hash on the **OLD** password and compare it with the md5 hashed password stored in the database.

The reason why you need to compare the hash instead of decrypting it is because it is not possible to reverse a hashed password and get back its original value.

If the comparison of the hashed password is successful and is validated, hash the **NEW** password and store it in the database.

There are a couple of examples available on the internet, such as:

[Java MD5 Hashing Example - Mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-md5-hashing-example/)

[Java MD5 example - Java development tutorials and examples](http://www.asjava.com/core-java/java-md5-example/)

If you face any problems, you are welcome to post your code here.

Comment: MD5 and all such has functions are insufficient for password verifiers, use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions.

Comment: The point is he want's to shoot his users in the foot. Do you want to help him? Will you be there to take part of the blame when the users are compromised? We know that just hashing passwords with MD5 is not even close to secure. Please consider the users.

Comment: How about server-side validations?